GeoLite2-City: Is either missing or outdated, downloading
When attempting to download data from GeoLite2 using Yarn or downloading from the MaxMind official site, it fails with the following error:
Error Message: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND mm-prod-geoip-databases.a2649acb697e2c09b632799562c076f2.r2.cloudflarestorage.com
Steps Taken:
yarn add geolite2

Did you get the answer? We are facing same issue

Same here, also facing this issue.

What fixed it for me was adding your maxmind account-id to either .env or package.json file, as suggested in https://github.com/runk/node-geolite2#readme. The license-key only flow must have been depreciated recently.
